# f-related vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Here is the question:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds and let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map. A vector field $X$ on $M$ and a vector field $Y$ on $N$ are said to be $f$-related if
> $$df_p(X_p)=Y_{f(p)},\forall p\in M.$$ This means that for every function $$h:N\rightarrow R$$
> $$X_p[h\circ f]=Y_{f(p)} h.$$Suppose that $X$ is $f$-related to $Z$ and $Y$ is $f$-related to $W$. Show that $[X,Y]$ is $f$-related to $[Z,W]$.

I know I have to prove that $$df_p([x,y])=[df_p(x),df_p(y)]_{f(p)}$$But that I can not figure out this calculation.

Comment: I'm confused by your equation $T_pf(X_p)=Y_{f(p)}$. Should this read $f_*(X_p)=Y_{f(p)}$? Then we have $X_p(h\circ f)=f_*(X_p)(h)=Y_{f(p)}(h)$ and your problem is just showing how push-forwards and commutators interact.

Comment: Yes, you are right about $T_pf(X_p)=Y_{f(p)}$.

Comment: But I still got confused about how to push-forwards. Could you please show me some details. Got really despaired.

Comment: I would suggest to look at the proof of proposition 4.2.25 at page 281 in [this amazing book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387967905).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the delay, I have been away for a few days. This calculation is horrible and I don't guarantee that this is the best way to do this. I just did it in coordinates and it seems to work.

We want to show that

$$f_*[X,Y]=[f_*(X),f_*(Y)]$$

We will show this by showing that both sides act the same way on functions on $N$ and so must be the same vector field.

Let $h:N\to\mathbb R$, we have by definition

$$f_*([X,Y])(h)=[X,Y](h\circ f)$$

We use coordinates $x^i$ for $M$ and $y^m$ for $N$. We have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}f_*([X,Y])(h)&=[X,Y](h\circ f)(x)\\
&=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(h\circ f)\right)(x)-Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(X^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(h\circ f)\right)(x)\\
&=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(Y^j\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^i}(x)\right)-Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(X^j\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^i}(x)\right)\\
&=X^i\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^i}(x)-Y^i\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^i}(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

While going from the other end
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\phantom a[f_*(X),f_*(Y)](h)&=f_*(X)(f_*(Y)(h))-f_*(X)(f_*(Y)(h))\\
&=f_*(X)\left(Y^j\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\right)-f_*(Y)\left(X^j\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\right)\\
&=X^iY^j\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^m\partial y^n}(f(x))+X^i\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^m}\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\\
&\phantom=-Y^iX^j\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^m\partial y^n}(f(x))-Y^i\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^m}\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}(f(x))\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\\
&=X^i\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))-Y^i\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y^m}(f(x))\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We have now shown that both sides are the same. In this derivation I have used the chain rule as well as the Jacobian, some cancellations and the fact that $\frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}(f(x))\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial y^m}(x)=\delta^k_j$.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question recently and decided to finally create an account. Your question relates to the commutation of the pushforward map and the Lie-bracket which is why the below proof together with the fact that the vector fields are $f$-related (or $\varphi$ in my case) should solve the problem.

*Theorem:* Given a smooth map $\varphi:M\rightarrow N$ between two manifolds $M$ and $N$ and two vector fields $X,Y \in \Gamma(M)$ the pushforward map $\varphi_*$ commutes with the Lie-bracket, namely $\varphi_* [X,Y] = [\varphi_*X, \varphi_*Y]$.

*Proof:* Let a smooth function $g\in C^{\infty}(N)$ and a point $p\in M$ be given. We first note that from $\varphi_* (X)_{\varphi(p)}(g) = X_p (\varphi^* g) = X_p (g \circ \varphi)$ we deduce that $\varphi_* (X)(g) \circ \varphi = X (g \circ \varphi)$. We use this fact to calculate
\begin{align*}
\varphi_* [X,Y]_{\varphi(p)}(g) &= [X,Y]_{p}(g \circ \varphi)\\
                          &= X_p \circ Y(g \circ \varphi) - Y_p \circ X(g \circ \varphi)\\
                          &= X_p (\varphi_*(Y)(g) \circ \varphi) - Y_p( \varphi_*(X)(g) \circ \varphi)\\
                          &= \varphi_* X_{\varphi(p)} (\varphi_*(Y)(g)) - \varphi_* Y_{\varphi(p)} ( \varphi_*(X)(g))\\
                          &= [\varphi_* X, \varphi_* Y]_{\varphi(p)}(g)\\
\end{align*}
This implies that indeed $\varphi_* [X,Y] = [\varphi_* X, \varphi_* Y]$. While a proof using coordinates was given, some may prefer a coordinate free approach.

Comment: The expression $φ_∗(X)(g)∘φ$ does not make sense, since $φ_∗(X)(g)$ is a function from $M$ to $R$: $φ_∗(X)(g)(p) = φ_{∗p}(X(p))(g)$. By definition of differential, $φ_∗(X)(g)=X(g∘φ)$, which does make sense. In fact, ${φ_∗(X)}_{φ(p)}(g)$ does not make sense either.